# Does Sosuke, Son of Seshiro's deathtouch-like ability combo with Matsu-Tribe Sniper?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have a [Sosuke, Son of Seshiro](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSosuke%2c%20Son%20of%20Seshiro%5d) and a [Matsu-Tribe Sniper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMatsu-Tribe%20Sniper%5d) on my field.

Sosuke's ability is:

> Whenever a Warrior you control deals combat damage to a creature, destroy that creature at end of combat.

and Matsu-Tribe Sniper's (which is a "Snake warrior archer") effect is:

> {T}: Matsu-Tribe Sniper deals 1 damage to target creature with flying.

(only listing the relevant effect for this question)

If I tap Matsu-Tribe Sniper to deal 1 damage to let's say [Courier Griffin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCourier%20Griffin%5d), which  is a 2/3 flying creature, would that destroy Courier Griffin because a warrior dealt damage? Or does that not count as combat damage? I'm pretty sure this isn't how that works but I would like a second opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The damaged creature will not be destroyed.**

"Combat damage" is a specific subcategory of damage. The only way to deal Combat damage is during the combat damage step in the combat phase of a turn. From the Glossary in the comprehensive rules:

> **Combat Damage**
>
> > Damage dealt during the combat damage step by attacking creatures and blocking creatures as a consequence of combat. See rule 510, “Combat Damage Step.”

Any other damage dealt, such as from the activated ability of [Matsu-Tribe Sniper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMatsu-Tribe%20Sniper%5d), is just damage; it is not "combat damage". Even if it took place during the combat step; it wasn't damage that was dealt as a result of attacking or blocking.